# XSLT add attributes to processed nodes with output to result-document

Tags: xslt, saxon

this is sample xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"                       
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"                       
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog                      
        http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.6.xsd                       
        http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog">
  <changeSet id="1" author="a">
    <createTable tableName="TABLE1">
      <column>
      </column>
    </createTable>
  </changeSet>
  <changeSet id="1-1" author="a">
    <createSequence sequenceName="SEQ_TABLE1" />
  </changeSet>
  <changeSet id="4" author="A">
    <createTable tableName="TABLE4">
      <column>
      </column>
    </createTable>
  </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

this is template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:transform version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"               xpath-default-namespace="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
  <xsl:variable name="coreTables"                  select="('TABLE1','TABLE2')"/>
  <xsl:template match="node()[not(self::*)]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="databaseChangeLog">
    <!-- CORE-->
    <xsl:comment>CORE TABLES</xsl:comment>
    <xsl:variable name="coreTablesVariable" select="changeSet[createTable/@tableName=$coreTables]"/>
    <xsl:comment>CORE SEQUENCES</xsl:comment>
    <xsl:variable name="coreSequencesVariable" select="changeSet[createSequence[starts-with(@sequenceName, 'SEQ_') and substring-after(@sequenceName, 'SEQ_') = $coreTables]]"/>
    <xsl:comment>CORE INDEXES</xsl:comment>
    <xsl:variable name="coreIndexesVariable" select="changeSet[createIndex/@tableName=$coreTables]"/>
    <xsl:comment>CORE FOREIGN CONSTRAINTS</xsl:comment>
    <xsl:variable name="coreForeignConstraintsVariable" select="changeSet[addForeignKeyConstraint/@baseTableName=$coreTables]"/>
    <xsl:comment>CORE VIEWS</xsl:comment>
    <xsl:variable name="coreViewsVariable" select="changeSet[createView/@viewName=$coreTables]"/>
    <xsl:call-template name="createChangeLog">
      <xsl:with-param name="outputFile" select="'core-changelog.xml'"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="changeLogContent" select="$coreTablesVariable,$coreSequencesVariable,$coreIndexesVariable,$coreForeignConstraintsVariable,$coreViewsVariable"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template name="createChangeLog">
    <xsl:param name="outputFile"/>
    <xsl:param name="changeLogContent"/>
    <xsl:result-document encoding="UTF-8" indent="true" method="xml" href="{$outputFile}">
      <databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"                                               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"                                               xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog                                               http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.6.xsd                                               http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog" logicalFilePath="TODO">
        <xsl:copy-of select="$changeLogContent"/>
      </databaseChangeLog>
    </xsl:result-document>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

I'd like to add to output xml processed inside `createChangelogTemplate` to each element `<changeSet>` another attribute (`context="legacy"`). I was trying to add another template which matches `databaseChangelog/changeSet` with additional `xsl:attribute` element but that didn't worked for me. If is there way how to do this in one place that would be nice, because I will need to prepare more sections like `CORE`.

I'm using xslt 2.0 and saxon 9.8he.

Answer (score 1):

Use a separate `mode` i.e. instead of `<xsl:copy-of select="$changeLogContent"/>` use `<xsl:apply-templates select="$changeLogContent" mode="legacy"/>`, then set up e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="changeSet" mode="legacy">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
    <xsl:attribute name="context">legacy</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

If further processing of the attributes and or the child nodes is necessary then change the `<xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>` and/or the `<xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>` to use `xsl:apply-templates mode="#current"` and set up further templates for the mode that perform any processing.

Comment: That works for that what was in original question. I've added missing part in which I'm selecting all nodes which were not processed (see `UNMATCHED`). This part is now broken, in final file I only see some texts from some changeSets but not what was there before. Can you please suggest what would be the best option to not break also unmatched output? Thank you

Comment: Please don't change your requirements once a problem has been solved. Ask a new question if necessary, showing in the question description which result you want and which one you get.